# removing the duplicate and sorting a string array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, collections

I'm trying to remove the duplicates and sort the String array but I'm unable to do it. I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong. Please check the code.

```
String [] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};


Set st = new HashSet();
st.add(s);

Array.sort(st);
```

When I do this, I'm getting this error.

> The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Set).

As per my sense we should first remove duplicates by using the Set interface and then we have to sort them.  But I'm unable to print even the st reference variable also([[Ljava.lang.String;@1d9dc39]) getting this error.

Please help me.

Comment: `TreeSet` is what you need .

Comment: @JasonSperske but im getting the following exception for treeset.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
 at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
 at com.ani.sample.Mango.main(Mango.java:70)

Comment: With `st.add(s);` you are adding the *array* to the set. You have to add the *elements* of the array to the set. You can do this with `set.addAll(Arrays.asList(s))` or a `for` loop. These problems could be avoided if you used generics....

Comment: I added a quick implementation, but honestly there are a lot of great answers here

Answer (score 2):

You cannot sort a set with the Array.sort().. As gravitas mentioned this is because a set has no order. It's just a mass of objects.

You have to add the elements in the set to an array or something else that has an order, and then sort them

Or you could use an arraylist, and use Collections.sort()

Something like

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(set);

Collections.sort(list);
```

This woiuld sort your list according to the natural order of the objects contained in the list.

Comment: This makes sense because there is no such thing as order in a set. The concept of order exists in an array, however.

Comment: @gravitas: I'm getting the exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
 at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
 at com.ani.sample.Mango.main(Mango.java:71)

Answer (score 1):

```
   String [] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};
     Set st = new TreeSet();
     st.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Comment: prints:[a, d, m, x, y], 
you can convert it back to array with **st.toArray()** if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String sortAndRemoveDuplicates(String s) {
    return List.of(s.split("")).stream()
        .sorted()
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> sortedUnique = 
    new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String [] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};
     List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s);
     Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
     list = new ArrayList<>(set);
     Collections.sort(list);
     //Iterate the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick TreeSet example with output (I didn't know which answer to add this to, but feel free to copy it, as a lot of people here are telling the OP to do the same basic thing) (here it is cleaned up a bit).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SO {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    //[a, y, x, a, d, y, m]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clean(s)));
    //[a, d, m, x, y]
  }

  public static String[] clean(String[] input) {
    TreeSet<String> unique = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(input));
    return unique.toArray(new String[unique.size()]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use TreeSet

```
String [] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};

Set<String> newSet= new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi solution for your problem is as below code

String [] s = {"a", "y", "x","a","d", "y","m"};

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s);

    TreeSet<String> sortedSet = new  TreeSet<String>(list);


    System.out.println(sortedSet);
```

here first convert the array of string into list, then put that list to treeset which will remove the duplicates and sorts it.

2nd way is
add each string from the array into set(to remove duplicates) then convert it into list then use collections.sort(list);

code for the same is  as below

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for (String str : s) {
        set.add(str);

    }
    List<String> strArr = new ArrayList<String>(set);
    Collections.sort(strArr);
```

let me know if have any doubts.